# cookies not being deleted in ff & firebug

Tags: jquery, cookies, firebug, session-cookies

I feel like I'm missing something obvious... but does firebug interfere with cookie deletion?  I have deleted them manually

```
>>>document.cookie
"noticecount=1; sessionid=adba186e765d007a93; "
>>>document.cookie='';
>>>document.cookie
"noticecount=1; sessionid=adba186e765d007a93; "
```

tried using jquery.cookie:

```
>>> $.cookie('imgpath')
"cv.jpg"
>>> $.cookie('imgpath',null)
undefined
>>> $.cookie('imgpath')
"cv.jpg"
```

Also, from looking at live http headers, I can see that the changed cookies aren't sent in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `document.cookie`, if you want to `delete` a cookie, you can not just assign `document.cookie` to `''`, instead you need to add the cookie to `document.cookie` but with an expiration time which is in the past.

Comment: hmm, ok.  looks like firebug was in that mode where you can't change any variables.  works now, thanks.